# Text search with projection in MongoDB & Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to do a text search and apply projection to the returned documents via the Node.js API in MongoDB?
The code below does not apply the projection and I get the entire document back, however I am only after the person property.

`collection.find({ $text: { $search: 'hello' } }, { person: 1 }).toArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use `project` method like this:

```
db.collection('collectionName').find({ $text: { $search: 'hello' } }).project({ person: 1 });
```

As stated in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) this should be way how you can do projection with MongoDB Node.js library. The example you have provided is how can you do projection in Mongo Shell.